# I am trying to write a 10-bit register and filling it using a for loop, the output keeps giving xxxxxxxxxx

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

Here is my Verilog code with the test bench:

```
// 10 Bits SourceRegister

module SourceRegister (Clk, Q);
output reg [9:0] Q;
reg integer i,D;
input Clk;

always @(posedge Clk)

for (i=0; i < 1024; i++)
begin

Q[i] <= D;
D++;

end
endmodule


module Testbench;
 
reg CLK;
wire [9:0] Q;

SourceRegister SR(CLK, Q);

always #5 CLK <= ~CLK;
initial begin

  #20 $display(" output = %b",  Q);
  #5 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

and here is the output:

```
output = xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What is the initial value of D?

Comment: I tried to inialize D to 0 and it gives the same output.

Comment: Your source register code is setting every possible value of Q at every clock cycle.  A bit can only have one value at a time, you are asking it to have many, if you try and assign zero and one at the same time you get X.

Comment: @JayM how can I fix that problem?

Comment: See answer.  Note you also did Q[i] = D.  In rewriting I assumed this was not what you meant as this would imply Q is an array of signals 1024 bits wide.

Comment: I just noticed you put system-verilog in your tags. Did you intend this to have a system verilog style answer?  The answer I gave is in Verilog.  I can change it to SV if required.

Comment: No, I was just willing it approch ASAP to many people so I can have the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember

1: Verilog is based on the C syntax, so it is case sensitive.

2: Unless there is some sort of delay, e.g. #TIME in a testbench or always@ in RTL then every assignment happens at the same time, no matter how complex.

3: The style of Verilog you are using is old, (similar to original C) consider a newer style as it's more explicit.

4:  In your code there are two basic problems:

i. The following would try and apply all the values 0..1023 to the signal Q on every clock cycle. It is also verbose as Q D and i are all the same value.

```
always @(posedge Clk)

for (i=0; i < 1024; i++)
begin
  Q[i] <= D;
  D++;
end
```

ii. The assignment `Q[i] <= D` implies that Q is an array of bits and you arre assigning one bit per loop expansion, which I don't think is your intention.

---

**Reworked Code (tested in Vivado 2022)**

NOTE: I added an improvement, using an  `initial` block to ensure CLK and RST have a valid logic state. Otherwise if, for instance, CLK had the value Z then the assignment CLK <= ~CLK is meaningless.

SourceRegister.v

```
// 10 Bits SourceRegister

module SourceRegister #(
    parameter unsigned reg_size = 10
  )(
    input wire Clk,
    input wire Reset,
    output wire unsigned [reg_size-1:0] Q
);

reg unsigned [reg_size-1:0] D;

assign Q = D;

always @(posedge Clk)
  if (Reset == 1)
    D <= 0;
  else
    D <= (2**(reg_size)-1)?D + 1:0;

endmodule
```

tb_SR.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module Testbench;

  parameter reg_size = 10;

  reg CLK;
  wire unsigned [reg_size-1:0] Q;
  reg RST;

  SourceRegister#(
    .reg_size (reg_size)
  ) SR (
    .Clk (CLK),
    .Reset (RST),
    .Q (Q)
  );

  // 10ns clock cycle
  always #5 CLK <= ~CLK;


  initial begin
    CLK <= 0;
    #1;
    RST <= 1;
    #20;
    RST <= 0;
    #200 $display(" output = %b",  Q);
    #5 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: It looks I am missing many things, thanks for the answer I appreciate it.

Comment: I can recommend taking some online classes. Just over a year ago I had to move from VHDL to SV in a short time and found  this site very useful: https://www.udemy.com/topic/systemverilog/ 25 or so years ago I did VHDL course with these guys. https://www.doulos.com/training